# When using git and rebasing interactive with EDITOR=emacs, using control-g kills emacs

Tags: git, emacs

While doing an interactive rebase on the command line with the editor set to emacs (the one included with macOS, emacs 22.1.1), if I use control-g within emacs when editing a commit message for a squash, emacs gets killed. Why would that happen?

This only happens when using the second invocation of emacs to edit the squashed commit message, not the first one that edits the rebase todo list. For example, if you do an interactive rebase with emacs as the editor,

```
$ EDITOR=emacs git rebase -i somebranch
```

emacs will come up letting you edit the rebase todo list. If you edit it to squash a commit like this,

```
p somehash
p othersha
s thirdsha
```

If you press control-g at this point, it's fine. Using control-x control-s you can save and continue, then git rebase will bring up emacs again to edit the commit message for squashing the last two commits. If you use control-g then, emacs will terminate immediately taking you back to the shell prompt. You use control-g in emacs frequently like you'd use esc in vim.

I tested this with vim and pico and they didn't have a problem with control-g when editing the commit message. I also tried with a fresh user account to make sure I didn't set something weird with the shell or emacs init files.

Comment: Is there some way to upgrade Emacs? Ver 22 was released in something like 2005 or 6.

Comment: Yes but this happens with any Mac dev machine I use, so I'd like to figure out how to fix it. Maybe something with the TTY?

Comment: Emacs makes ^G send SIGQUIT via the tty pgroup. This seems to take you back to the shell with the interactive rebase not yet started. I tried the obvious simple workaround (ignore SIGQUIT initially) and that does not help, so I'm not sure what remains. Note that other editors don't use SIGQUIT like this.